# Camel loggingErrorHandler not woking

Tags: apache-camel

```
<camel:errorHandler id="myErrorHandler" type="LoggingErrorHandler" level="ERROR" logName="myLoggingErrorHandler"/>
    <camel:camelContext  errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler" trace="true">

        <camel:route>  <!-- errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler" -->
            <camel:from uri="file://src/resources?fileName=bookstore.xml" />
            <camel:split>
                <camel:xpath>//book/[@category='WEB']/author/text()</camel:xpath>
                <camel:log message="Main route: '${body}'" />
                </camel:split>
            <!-- <camel:to uri="stream:out"/> -->
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

Errors are getting logged but not with the name myLoggingErrorHandler as should be. That is how they were without using errorHandler. Please guide.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: And what name are the errors being logged with? Also the logging error handler is only logging the message, not the stacktrace etc.